# node.current shows up as null when using useRef(), despite using within useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

My goal is to large scrollable modal where if the item provided to the modal changes (there is a "More projects" section at the bottom which should change the modal content), the modal automatically scrolls to the top. Since I can't use the `window` object, other sources seem to indicate a `ref` is the best way to go. However, I keep getting the error `node.current is undefined` at the time of compiling.

I saw elsewhere that this should be avoidable by working with the `ref` within a `useEffect` hook, since this will ensure the `ref` has been initialized by the time it runs, however this is not happening here.

```
const PortfolioModal = ({
  open,
  handleClose,
  item,
  setItem,
  ...props
}) => {
  const node = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    node.current.scrollIntoView()
  }, [item]);

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open} fullWidth={true} maxWidth='lg'>

      <div ref={node}></div>
      <Content>
        {a bunch of stuff is here}
          <PortfolioFooter
            backgroundImage={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/backgrounds/panel5.png`}
            item={item}
            setItem={setItem}
          />
        </FlexContainer>
        </Content>
    </Dialog>
    
  )
};
```

EDIT: Additional note -- I initially wrapped the entire component with a div with a ref and tried to use `scrollTop` and I did not receive an error, but there was also no scrolling, so I thought I would try using `scrollIntoView` with an invisible element.

Comment: See inside the Dialog component, maybe it has a delay rendering its children

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, based on [this post](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9186):

```
const nodeRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (nodeRef.current) {
      nodeRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'start'
      });
    }
    
  }, [item]);

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open} fullWidth={true} maxWidth='lg' scroll="body">
      <div ref={node => {
          nodeRef.current = node;
      }}>
      <Content>
         {content}
       </Content>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
```

Comment: The reason why this works is because on the initial render pass over your stateless functional component, the `nodeRef` hasn't been attached to your `div`. Therefore, when the `useEffect` is fired, there's no reference within the `current` slice of the `nodeRef` object. When the `nodeRef` is attached to your `div` in that first pass, a re-render is fired by the `useRef` hook, and thusly, the useEffect is re-fired, as well. This time, however, there is a node in the `nodeRef.current`, entering into the if statement defined within your `useEffect`.